# Erro de execução em inicialização de bibliotecas

Tags: python

```
import sys
import tkinter

counter = 0

def update():
    global count, b
    counter += 1
    b.config(text = "click cont = " + str(count))
    print("updating")

root = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(root)
b.configure(background="yellow", text="click count = 0", command=update)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

```c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/miopo/untitled-1.py", line 12, in <module>
    root = tkinter.Tk()
  File "C:\Users\miopo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2012, in __init__
    baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: eu uso o wing 101 como ide

Comment: Como executou o arquivo? Por padrão, se a classe `Tk` não possuir o valor de `basename` definido na sua chamada ela buscará o nome do *script* executado a partir dos argumentos da linha de comando; e o primeiro argumento, `sys.argv[0]`, sempre é definido na execução.

Comment: eu executei usando o wing 101 eu apenas digitei o codigo na ide e selecionei executar debug

Comment: Enzo, tenta executar seu arquivo direto da linha de comando, sem ser pela IDE.

Comment: A partir da linha de comando seu código funcionou perfeitamente aqui: https://i.imgur.com/aEAgvyS.jpg

Answer (score -2):

**Postei como resposta porque ainda não posso comentar em perguntas dos outros**

Já tentou usar
`from tkinter import *`
`root = Tk()`
?

**Fiz algumas adaptações no código que fizeram com que ele rodasse sem erros aqui pra mim:**

O método update (aqui na minha máquina) não conseguia acesso à variável `counter`, então a coloquei em uma classe junto com a responsabilidade do incremento.

```
import sys
import tkinter

class Contador():
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = 0

    def incrementa(self):
        self.valor += 1

contador = Contador()

def update():
    global count, b
    contador.incrementa()
    count = str(contador.valor)
    b.config(text = "click cont = " + count)
    print("updating")

root = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(root)
b.configure(background="yellow", text="click count = 0", command=update)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: E por que isso resolveria o problema?

Comment: sim mais mesmo assim dar erro isso tambem acontece com outros modulos como o turtle e alem disso eu conseguir abrir uma janela do tkinter no interpratador

Comment: [É possível (e desejável) reduzir o requisito para comentar?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/817/5878)

Comment: O erro não pode ser apenas de lógica? E não no import? `builtins.IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: eu usei o modulo math dessa mesma forma e funcionou corretamente